# Blob gets saved as damaged image

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, crop, form-data

So in my jQuery I'm using FormData API to post some data to Laravel controller. The blob itself is taken from cropper plugin, the code itself looks as folows:

```
image_cropper.cropper('getCroppedCanvas').toBlob(function (blob) {
          var formData = new FormData();

          formData.append('image_url', blob);
          console.log(formData.get('image_url'));
          $.ajax({
              url: "{{action('Admin\AdminDashboardController@postCreateEdit')}}",
              data: formData,
              processData: false,
              contentType: false,
              type: 'POST',
              success: function(data){
                $('#carCreateEditModal').modal('close');
              }
            });
        });
```

The console log prints out this object:

```
lastModified
:
1472579954758
lastModifiedDate
:
Tue Aug 30 2016 20:59:14 GMT+0300 (FLE Daylight Time)
name
:
"blob"
size
:
525372
type
:
"image/png"
webkitRelativePath
:
""
__proto__
:
File
```

When I'm checking if the formdata has file in my controller it is said that the file exists, and then I simply put it into folder:

```
if($this->request->hasFile('image_url')!=''){
            $image = $this->request->file('image_url');
            file_put_contents(storage_path().'/'.$time.'.'.$image->extension(), $image);
        }
```

The saved file has png extension and is 1 KB large, and could not be open by any file explorers. Changing extensions manually does not help.

Is the problem somewhere in my code or is it something about the plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of file_put_contents you can use `\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile::move`. See the code below:

```
$image->move(storage_path(), $time.'.'.$image->extension());
```

Comment: I got an error 500: The file "C:\laragon\tmp\phpD0EC.tmp" does not exist

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't know why, but it worked to do as follows in controller:

```
$file = file_get_contents($image);
file_put_contents($path, $file);
```